# Switching from DOS to Linux on embedded system

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, ubuntu

I was recently tasked with performing a feasibility study based around switching from using DOS to Linux for use as an OS to run our industrial control software (developed internally). In a nutshell I have been restricted to using Ubuntu 8.04 (with a vendor supplied kernel upgrade providing drivers for the hardware on the board). As this is no longer supported I am unable to update or install software meaning that I am stuck using gcc version 4.2. I want to be able to use C++ and preferably boost libraries but currently this seems like I will not be able to do so.

Basically I am asking how do companies/professionals go about using Linux as a development environment? Is what I described above a common occurrence? Do you simply pick a version and a compiler and stick with it throughout the product lifetime to ensure that the development environment doesn't change too much or can you freely upgrade the kernel, compiler etc. as you go along? Is it common to be constrained by what a particular vendor can provide. Would anyone be prepared to give their opinion as to whether ubuntu 8.04 is a suitable choice of OS for development of industrial control software?

I am not a linux expert at all, but my research and experimentation so far is leading me to conclusion that I should abandon the linux approach and use DOS. Our company has no linux knowledge and is very small and for personal career reasons I have no interest in learning redundant technology like DOS.

I realise this is not exactly a yes/no type question but any responses will be gratefully received.

Comment: Apparently it is still used for industrial device control systems... but I hear what you are saying.

Comment: How long will the software have to be supported for? Consider that Ubuntu 8.04 will reach its End Of Life in April 2013.

Comment: Starting from scratch, obviously no one would use DOS, but the likelihood here is that the solution is already working in DOS and likely has been for years, if not decades.  Why the decision to move?  Fear of no hardware support?  Also, there is nothing stopping you from installing any additional packages you want or need, given that you are willing to compile them yourself.

Comment: Also, were you using DOS because your software needed real-time response guarantees? Linux does not offer that by default. Something like (LinuxCNC)[linuxcnc.org] provides an ubuntu build with appropriate real time interrupt handling patches applied to the kernel for you.

Comment: @Rook I think this is basically the reasoning behind its use yes. The problem is we need to upgrade hardware to a new generation board and the vendor supports linux with a kernel mod for the hardware drivers. I am basically a desktop application developer and way way out of my depth - hence the pleas for advice. This kind of question you just cant get a general answer to on the web.

Comment: @Mathematician1975 When you say you can't update GCC you mean you can't 'sudo apt-get' it or that when you download the source/binary there is some incompatibility with other libraries? I have worked with many different versions of GCC on the same system, perhaps you can install a newer one just for your project. Take a look here: http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple

Comment: Yes I meant the sudo apt-get route. I will try to install from scratch and see what happens.

Comment: @mathematician1975 the fact that ubuntu is dropping repository support doesn't mean much. A lot of places run on specific versions of the kernel that is very old. Most other things you can usually manually install on top of your distro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC 4.2 has no C++11 support but the C++03 support should be good and you should be able to find a version of Boost that can deal with that quite easily.

Ultimately, Linux has many upsides you won't find in DOS- for example, no segmentation, virtual memory, and such things that will make it easier and faster to develop software, not to mention additional libraries you might need, as absolutely nobody whatsoever will support DOS today.

Comment: Well that is one of my problems - I can't get g++ installed on the board. Presumably because 8.04 is no longer supported.

Comment: @mathematician1975: you can always compile it yourself

Comment: @mathematician1975: Exactly. If you get the source for the latest version, you might, and I say, might get it work. Or, because this board probably doesn't have the power to compiler, why can't you just cross-compile? Find out the architecture of the board, cross compile later `libc`s and other libraries for it, and compile your code on your macine and then cross it to the board in binary form. As long as you have the libraries (which you also cross compile) you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for all answer and comments. This has been very useful indeed to me.

Answer (score 1):

With linux-based systems there's not much reason to stick with fixed OS+toolchain version, because backwards compatibility is a very serious issue in Unix-world. Sometimes it is good to target certain fixed system, but frankly these are rather rare, and even then the development can be done on up-to-date systems as long as testing is done on the target macine/platform.

Basically you could just upgrade to for example Ubuntu 12.04 LTS(long term support) for development and stick with it, it is very unlikely that there would be any sorts of uncompatibility problems on the target platform/machine.

Comment: But this is a special board that only has drivers for Ubuntu 8.04. That's the problem.

Comment: @Linuxios, if the drivers work in 8.04, but not in newer releases, then those drivers are piece of crap and should not be used under any circumstances, at least not in their current form. I've heard sentences like "for this embedded programming, I need this specific version of OS", but only when "OS" was "Windows". Once again: don't use crappy drivers, even if they are "the only" drivers. Before starting further work, **get better drivers**.

Comment: @Linuxios That's why I wrote "for development" when suggesting upgrading. You can develop on newer 12.04 version of Ubuntu and target the 8.04 version platform.

Comment: @Griwes vendor claims to support ubuntu 9.04 and 10.04 but I have been unable to install either of them onto the boards compact flash card using USB CD. 8.04 is the only 'supported' version I can install.

Comment: I know. That's what I suggested in one of my comments in @DeadMG's answer. Use a modern Linux OS for development and cross-compile for the control board. I know what you mean about better drivers, but this sounds like one of those proprietary-hardware-only-their-drivers work.

Comment: @mathematician1975: What about Debian? Linux Mint? Ubuntu Server? Any Debian based (or Ubuntu based) distro might work with the drivers. And, this may be far fetched, but what if you just ran a simple program on the boards that took commands through a port that was connected to a computer capable of actually running good software? Then you wouldn't be tied to archaic software (DOS) or unsupported software (8.04). Note: Even if you can only get 8.04, its better than DOS.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries and such tend to change between Linux distros, new versions of linux distros, and other *nix OSes.

I once worked on a C++ application that had to run on both Windows and RHEL.  I was the 'Linux guy' on the team, so I got to deal with coaxing all the open-source linux libraries we were using to build and work on Windows (using cygwin), and getting the latest changes made by the devs working on Windows to work on Linux.

Midway through development, we upgraded to a newer version of RHEL.  It was not a fun experience.  Library versions had changed, some had been removed in favor of other 'equivalent' libs, etc.  Shaking out all of the problems caused by changing gcc versions took a little while too (granted, the newer gcc version was a bit less forgiving and exposed some stuff in our code that probably wasn't quite right anyway).

A couple of days before a big demo, management informed us that the app needed to run on Solaris as well.  That was not a trivial task -- Solaris is NOT Linux.  They hinted about wanting it to run on IRIX at one point.  Glad that didn't happen.

I would recommend that you pick a specific version of a Linux distro, gcc, etc. and stick with it throughout development.  Upgrading that stuff can happen later, when the software is in maintenance.  RHEL offers long-term support, at a cost.  You might also consider the newly released Ubuntu 12.04 LTS